# Osm2pgsql error, unable to open

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I have a problem when I run osm2pgsql for Liechtenstein (small dataset). I have a VM running Ubuntu (64-bit) with 5GB of RAM. This is the error I get:

```
osm2pgsql --create --slim --cache 512 --number-processes 2 --hstore --style ~/osm/openstreetmap-carto/openstreetmap-carto.style --multi-geometry ~/osm/liechtenstein-latest.osm.pbf
osm2pgsql SVN version 0.88.1 (64bit id space)

Using built-in tag processing pipeline
Using projection SRS 900913 (Spherical Mercator)
Setting up table: planet_osm_point
Setting up table: planet_osm_line
Setting up table: planet_osm_polygon
Setting up table: planet_osm_roads
Allocating memory for dense node cache
Allocating dense node cache in one big chunk
Allocating memory for sparse node cache
Sharing dense sparse
Node-cache: cache=512MB, maxblocks=65536*8192, allocation method=11
Mid: pgsql, scale=100 cache=512
Setting up table: planet_osm_nodes
Setting up table: planet_osm_ways
Setting up table: planet_osm_rels

Reading in file: ~/osm/liechtenstein-latest.osm.pbf
Unable to open ~/osm/liechtenstein-latest.osm.pbf
Error occurred, cleaning up
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Here is some info about the performance of my machine
#memory usage according to top
KiB Mem: 5208300 total, 1586372 used, 3621928 free, 43784 buffers
KiB Swap: 2096124 total, 0 used, 2096124 free. 532136 cached Mem

My kernel parameters are
kernel.shmall = 18446744073692774399
kernel.shmmax = 18446744073692774399
vm.overcommit_memory = 0
```

Comment: Is the file for sure in ~/osm/liechtenstein-latest.osm.pbf ?